# Jenkins running in container with centOS as base image?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, dockerhub

I just started learning docker and Jenkins and wanted to **run Jenkins inside a Docker container.**

- I'm referring to this [repo on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker). It has a `Dockerfile` ([Dockerfile link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile)) that uses `openjdk:8-jdk-stretch` as its **base image**
- I want to use `centOS`/any other smaller base image.
- I tried writing `FROM centOS` instead of `FROM openjdk:8-jdk-stretch` but that didn't work.
- I want it to run on HTTP port `9090` and AGENT port on
  `55000`.

The output that I got looks like this
[image: Output]

So this is what I did with the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl && rm -rf/var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
ARG http_port=9090
ARG agent_port=55000
```

Keeping all other changes same according to this `Dockerfile` ( [Dockerfile Link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) )

I want **my container to run Jenkins on CentOS**/any other smaller base image and able to push that container image to my DockerHub. I'm struck, any bits of help/lead will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Jenkins image size

If you want a smaller image, just use one of the following [image tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/tags):

- jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-slim (408 MB)
- jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-alpine (222 MB)

### Publishing ports

Now for the ports. The ports opened within the container don't matter since docker will offer you the ability to [*publish*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) them to whatever port you choose on the docker host.

In short, start your container with:

```sh
docker run -d \
    -p 9090:8080 \
    -p 55000:50000 \
    jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-alpine
```

### Adding files to the Jenkins container

If you need to add files to the Jenkins container, just use a volume:

```sh
docker run -d \
    -p 9090:8080 \
    -p 55000:50000 \
    -v /home/somewhere/workspace/:/my_data \
    jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-xxxx
```

### Adding software to the Jenkins image

#### jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-slim

The *slim* flavor image is based `FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim` which itself is based `FROM debian:stretch-slim`. Now that we know it is based on Debian, installing software can be done with `ap

```sh
FROM jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-slim 
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
      curl \
      git \
    && rm -rf/var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER jenkins
```

#### jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-alpine

In *Alpine* flavored images, you install software with [apk](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages).

```sh
FROM jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-alpine 
USER root
RUN apk --update add \
      curl \
      git 
USER jenkins
```

---

### CentOS Jenkins image

There is no official Jenkins docker images based on CentOS. While Making your own is possible, the time you will spend coming up with a working Dockerfile and the time you will have to spend to maintain it is most likely no worth the added value it would bring to you.

Comment: What if I want to write my own Docker file for it?.

Comment: After this, Should I just do `docker build -t <image-name> .` to create a container image out of that docker file?.

Comment: I want to use CentOS as the base image on top of which Jenkins will run. Can't I do that?

Comment: You can, but this much more work than using an already built image